# How to avoid grep command finding commented out strings in the source file?

Tags: scripts, grep

I am running a software where I want to check if `miniconda` is already installed. Therefore I've checked whether 'miniconda' or 'anaconda' strings in `.bashrc` file using the `grep` command. However, it also finds either of above strings which are commented out in the `.bashrc` file, which I do not want to have. How do I fix this? Relevant part of my `bashscript` looks as follows.

```
#Finding if miniconda or anaconda string is in bashrc  
if grep -qF -e miniconda -e anaconda "$HOME"/.bashrc ;then    
  echo "miniconda is found in .bashrc"
```

I've tested this by adding following lines in the `.bashrc` file.

```
#anaconda
#miniconda
```

**Terminal Output**

```
jen@scs400:/scratch$ source bash_script.sh     
miniconda is found in .bashrc
```

Comment: `grep -E '(ana|mini)conda' .bashrc`.

Comment: @Videonauth: Thanks it works! But could you please explain why this works?

Comment: @Videonauth I don't see how that excludes commented lines - doesn't it need some kind of anchor like `^[^#]*(ana|mini)conda`?

Comment: @steeldriver it doesn't this was just a wild shot in the dark, feel freee to write an exhausting answer if you like.

Comment: Your check for "miniconda is already installed" is incorrect/incomplete. Some users want to switch in and out of `miniconda` use, and keep the code to do this elsewhere. Some users `source`, or `.`, other files from within `~/.bashrc`,

Comment: @waltinator indeed... my dotfiles setup is quite complex. Better would be `{ type miniconda || type anaconda; } 2>/dev/null 1>&2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
if grep -qwE '^[^#]*(ana|mini)conda' "$HOME"/.bashrc ;then
    echo "miniconda/anaconda is found in .bashrc"
fi
```

Comment: Note this won't work reliably, because # can appear as a non-comment character as well.. For example: `search_string='#[0-9]+.* anaconda' `. Or `if [ "$1" -eq 3 ]; then echo "Arg #1 triggered change of target (value was 3)"; target="#$anaconda"; fi`. Or even `source '~/#scripts/.anaconda'` (or for extremophiles, a shebang I guess: `#!/bin/anaconda`, or some compiler preprocessor directive marked with a '#' ?!). The OP will have to consider whether such statements are likely to be an issue, though. If it's an issue, your best bet is to detect/filter out static strings using a few chained `sed`